# Angular - Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined at isAngularDecoratorMetadataExpression

Tags: angular, typescript

I've used Angular version 8.2.0. I want to build with this command:

`ng build --aot=true --prod --build-optimizer --configuration=dev --outputHashing=all`

But I got this error:

`ERROR in ./node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/fesm5/ng2-material-dropdown.js`

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined at isAngularDecoratorMetadataExpression`

The only usage `ng2-material-dropdown` in my project is related to `ngx-chips`. I've updated `ngx-chips` version but it does not work.

p.s. I use  `"typescript": "~3.5.3"`

Any suggestion?

Comment: Check this thread: https://gitmemory.com/issue/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill/573/542603349

Comment: Though my app uses Angular 6 I got the very same error. Solution for me was to downgrade ngx-chips to version 1.9.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an issue on ngx-chips and they solved it in the latest version of ngx-chips

https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips/issues/912

Answer (score 1):

From the answer https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips/issues/912#issuecomment-554780546

> My gut feeling is that it may be due to a package version (angular-devkit/build-angular):

`this is the version I use to build on v9: "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.19"`

`this is the version I use to build on v8": "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.8"`

> Can you try to use the same versions as above? Or share which exact versions you're using?